# AWS Android SDK Upload file to S3 but can't find it in the bucket

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am learning to build an Android App to upload a file to AWS S3. To get started, I followed the this [tutorial](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/S3TransferUtilitySample). Everything works well and I successfully uploaded files to my bucket.

From the abovementioned tutorial, I built an app to have a function to upload a file to my S3 bucket. I could run the program without any error message, however, the file could not be seen in my S3 bucket. I have searched similar discussions but cannot really solve it. Please see my following co

*build.gradle*

I implemented the required dependencies here

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.thanawin.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.6.+'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.6.+'
    implementation ('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.6.+@aar') { transitive = true }
}
```

*AndroidManifest.xml*

Here, I added *user-permission* and *service*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.thanawin.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService"
            android:enabled="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

*MainActivity.java*

Here, I upload an image file to my bucket

```
package com.example.thanawin.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferUtility;
import java.io.File;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferObserver;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TransferUtility transferUtility;
    private Util util;
    private TransferObserver observer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        util = new Util();
        transferUtility = util.getTransferUtility(this);

        TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(Constants.BUCKET_NAME, "aaa.jpg",
                new File("/sdcard/aaa.jpg")); // upload image "aaa.jpg"
    }
}
```

*Util.java*

This is for credential

```
package com.example.thanawin.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;

import com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferUtility;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Region;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;

public class Util {

    private AmazonS3Client sS3Client;
    private CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider sCredProvider;
    private TransferUtility sTransferUtility;


    private CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider getCredProvider(Context context) {
        if (sCredProvider == null) {
            sCredProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                    context.getApplicationContext(),
                    Constants.COGNITO_POOL_ID,
                    Regions.fromName(Constants.COGNITO_POOL_REGION));
        }
        return sCredProvider;
    }


    public AmazonS3Client getS3Client(Context context) {
        if (sS3Client == null) {
            sS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(getCredProvider(context.getApplicationContext()));
            sS3Client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.fromName(Constants.BUCKET_REGION)));
        }
        return sS3Client;
    }


    public TransferUtility getTransferUtility(Context context) {
        if (sTransferUtility == null) {
            sTransferUtility = TransferUtility.builder()
                    .context(context.getApplicationContext())
                    .s3Client(getS3Client(context.getApplicationContext()))
                    .defaultBucket(Constants.BUCKET_NAME)
                    .build();
        }

        return sTransferUtility;
    }
}
```

*Constants.java*

I defined my KEY here

```
package com.example.thanawin.myapplication;
public class Constants {
    public static final String COGNITO_POOL_ID = "MY_POOL_ID";
    public static final String COGNITO_POOL_REGION = "MY_POOL_REGION";
    public static final String BUCKET_NAME = "BUCKET_NAME";
    public static final String BUCKET_REGION = "BUCKET_REGION";
}
```

When running the code, there is no error but I cannot get the image file in the bucket. Any suggestion or comment would be appreciated

### Updated

1. I am using Android Studio version 3.1.2, SDK version 26.1.1, running on Android Virtual Device 7.1.1.
2. I found this message in Logcat where I use the same KEY and S3 privacy setting as I did in the tutorial

"D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider: Loading credentials from SharedPreferences
    No valid credentials found in SharedPreferences"

Comment: What is the SDK version you are using? Also what is the Android version? What is the name of the file and the key?

Comment: @Karthikeyan Thank you for your reply. I am using Andriod SDK version 26.1.1 and running on Android Virtual Device 7.1.1. Is the name of the file and the key are "aaa.jpg" in *MainActivity.java* ?

Comment: Can you follow this function https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/blob/master/S3TransferUtilitySample/src/com/amazonaws/demo/s3transferutility/UploadActivity.java#L443 to get the file path instead of new File("/sdcard/aaa.jpg")?

Comment: @Karthikeyan I will try to implement it in my code. By the way, I saw this message in logcat  "D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider: Loading credentials from SharedPreferences No valid credentials found in SharedPreferences".

Comment: This means that there are no valid credentials at this moment, but when the request to S3 is made, the credentials are fetched and stored and used for contacting S3.

Comment: Did you get this working?